# Access xmm registers in eBPF program

Tags: 64-bit, bcc, tracing

I am trying to use bcc-tools to trace a user process using uprobe, but some functions take floating point arguments. According to x86_64 ABI, these values are normally passed in the xmm registers.

The eBPF functions in bcc takes a `struct pt_regs *` argument and in that I can get access to (a copy of ?) most "usual" registers, but not the xmm registers.

Is there a way to accomplish this ? Or is this something that was overlooked in the design of eBPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** This is not an issue with BPF, neither uprobes nor kprobes can access AVX registers such as xmm registers.

---

uprobe programs are actually [loaded in the kernel as kprobe programs](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/2ddbc07782c3ca4115a0840882e42dfb0c88686d/src/python/bcc/__init__.py#L988) (i.e., `BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE`).

Contrary to most BPF programs, kprobe programs have access to an unmodified, unrestricted context argument at the hook point. What I mean is that the argument of BPF programs is often a mirror of the actual object given at the hook point, with accesses rewritten by the verifier. For example, several BPF programs take `struct __sk_buff` as argument, which is actually [a mirror of `sk_buff`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.7/source/net/core/filter.c#L3896) (see [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051729/bpf-translation-of-program-contexts/49128551#49128551) for more details). kprobe program, on the contrary, have access to the raw `struct pt_regs` object (the `convert_ctx_access` field of [`struct bpf_verifier_ops`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.7/source/include/linux/bpf.h#L179) is [null](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.7/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L584)).

From this we can conclude that kprobes (which receive `struct pt_regs`) don't have access to the AVX registers. So it's a limitation of kprobes and not of BPF. One reason for this might simply be the low support for AVX registers in the kernel. Please see [this StackOverflow answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475956/why-can-the-kernel-not-use-sse-avx-registers-and-instructions) for further information.